# Add google maps to fiori sapui5 app

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sapui5

I want to add google maps to my Fiori app. 
At this moment, I'm able to add google maps to my UI5 app by adding a `<script>` tag in `index.html` and successfully call the map to render. But when it comes to Fiori Launchpad, which launch my app not by `index.html` but `Component.js`, then it doesn't work. I've been working around but no hope. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code in controller file.

Instead of script in index file, load script once view is rendered

```js
onAfterRendering: function() {
 var me = this;
 this.loadGoogleMaps("google map API script", me.setMapData.bind(me));
},

// setMapData is a callback function for setting data such as longitude and lattitude

loadGoogleMaps: function(scriptUrl, callbackFn) {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.onload = function() {
        callbackFn();
 }
 script.src = scriptUrl;
 document.body.appendChild(script);
},
```

In this way you can use it inside Fiori launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a wrapper custom control that is responsible for the renndering of the map. Then you can place this control inside your view XML.

There is also this post: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/01/google-maps-library-for-ui5/

Comment: [Related talk](https://youtu.be/W3Qkev2yk9w?t=9m49s) by [Andreas Kunz](https://github.com/akudev)